# The disadvantages of mitsubishi lancer 2007

Tags: engine, brakes, automatic-transmission, performance, power

I am planing to buy a new car that has to be good enough to be used everyday . I have tried the speranza and the brilliance but weren't good and not reliable to be used everyday . Many friends suggested the mitsubishi espicially the mitsubishi lancer 2007 . So I want to know every disadvantage of it in every possible way and if its good enough to buy it or not. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy tiger. That's a lot of information you're asking for there. All I can say is that the Lancer is probably the best value for money sedan you can buy if you consider the feature level, engine and build quality. They're quite reliable, but parts are a bit expensive for my liking. But if you're one of those lucky people who live in a 1st world country, that won't be such a big problem.

Expensive things to look out for (not specifically a Lancer problem, but rather any car) are

- creaking power steering
- blown lights (may mean that there is a short somewhere which could at some point set fire to your wiring loom).
- Slipping clutch (revs go up but speed stays the same).
- difficulty getting the car into 1st and/or 2nd gear. This usually means the fluid level is low, but it can also mean the synchro gears are worn out and would need to be replaced.
- Electric components not in working order.
- ABS not ABS'ing.
- smoke from the tailpipe. Doesn't matter if it's white or black. It means that car wasn't taken care of and in modern cars, means you'll have to replace catalytic converters, MAF sensors, etc. Catalytic converters contain platinum, so it's a fair bet they're expensive to replace.

A Lancer is a great car. It's not immune to problems, but they're solid and good value for money.

Answer (score 0):

Reliability of any used car is dependent on how the previous owners maintained and treated the vehicle. If they never repaired worn parts, changed the oil (etc) then even the most durable cars can turn into giant money pits.
  Unknown variables make your question difficult to correctly answer without seeing the car in person. Have a trusted/capable shop check over the vehicle before you purchase, they know what to look/listen for and can give you a better idea how much money you'll be putting into the car over time.